# How can I monitor the device's audio output to be able to tell if sound is coming out of the speakers/headphone jack?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, swift2

I need to initiate an action immediately when the device begins outputting Audio. I am using an AVPlayer and am streaming audio files from Parse. Using other methods like waiting for (AVPlayer.currentTime() != nil) and (AVPlayer.rate > 0) are NOT accurate enough, I need to know exactly the time when audio beings to be output from the device. I have tried using AVAudioEngine, and then attaching an AVAudioNode that has an AVAudioNodeBus but I can not get it to work. Any advice or techniques would be excellent thank you!

here is my code for the AudioEngine. I instantiate AudioEngine at the instance level. when creating standardFormat I don't know what to use for the standardFormatWithSampleRate or for the channels block. The when I try to installTapOnBus I do not know what to use for the block so I put nil, but that triggers an error too. Any help would be appreciated, I am very new to iOS dev and have read through Apple's docs numerous times but I just can't wrap my head around it and I can't find any recent examples online.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

var iDArray = [String]()
var NameArray = [String]()


var durationInSeconds = Double()

var currentSong = String()




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    let ObjectIDQuery = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
    ObjectIDQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objectsArray: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        //objectsArray!.count != 0
        var objectIDs = objectsArray!

        for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1 {
                self.iDArray.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("objectId") as! String)
                self.NameArray.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("SongName") as! String)

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

    }

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        print("AVAudioSession Category Playback OK")
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("AVAudioSession is Active")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }



}

func grabSong () {


    let songQuery = PFQuery(className: "Songs")
    songQuery.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(iDArray[SelectedSongNumber], block: {
        (object: PFObject?, error : NSError?) -> Void in


        if let audioFile = object?["SongFile"] as? PFFile {
            let audioFileUrlString: String = audioFile.url!
            let audioFileUrl = NSURL(string: audioFileUrlString)!


            AudioPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: audioFileUrl)
            AudioPlayer.play()

    })

}

func audioFunction() {

    var audioPlayerNode = AVAudioNode()
    var audioBus = AVAudioNodeBus()


    var standardFormat = AVAudioFormat(standardFormatWithSampleRate: <#T##Double#>, channels: <#T##AVAudioChannelCount#>)


    AudioEngine.attachNode(audioPlayerNode)

    audioPlayerNode.outputFormatForBus(audioBus)

    audioPlayerNode.installTapOnBus(audioBus, bufferSize: 100, format: standardFormat, block: nil)

    if AudioEngine.running == true {
        print("the audio engine is running")
    } else {
        print("the audio engine is NOTTT running")
    }

}


func attachNode(audioNode : AVAudioNode) {
    AudioEngine.attachNode(audioNode)

    AudioEngine.outputNode
    print(AudioEngine.outputNode.description)

    if AudioEngine.running == true {
        print("the audio engine is running")
    } else {
        print("the audio engine is NOTTT running")
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return iDArray.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")
    cell?.textLabel!.text = NameArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell!
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

   SelectedSongNumber = indexPath.row
    grabSong()
}
```

}

Should I be using AVAudioSession instead? Or AVCaptureSession?

Comment: I'd be tempted to add a tap to an `AVPlayer`. Why don't you show your `AVAudioEngine` code? I'm curious why that didn't work.

Comment: Sorry about that, just added it

Comment: how are you actually playing the streaming audio files with `AVAudioEngine`?

Comment: I updated more of my code incase it helps clear anything up. I am not actually playing the streaming audio files with AudioEngine. I built the app using AVPlayer and now i realize that to get the precision i am looking for I need to somehow monitor the audio output and the only way (I think) I found to do that is by attaching an AVAudioNode

Comment: I really just want to know exactly when Audio begins to be output from the device. it doesn't have to be connected to my AVPlayer, I just want to monitor when certain parts of the hardware begin to be used... is this even possible?

Comment: You can do it by adding an audio tap to the AVPlayer!

Comment: I can't find any documentation on installing a tap on an AVPlayer, would you be able to explain? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an audio tap on an `AVPlayer` to understand when audio is actually playing/about to play. Basically, you get an audio tap callback just before the audio plays out the speaker/headphone jack.

Some complications: I'm not sure how to get the `AVAsset` tracks for some streaming types (pls, icecast) but remote (and local) mp3 files work fine.

```
var player: AVPlayer?

func doit() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "URL TO YOUR POSSIBLY REMOTE AUDIO FILE")!
    let asset = AVURLAsset(URL:url)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)

    let tapProcess: @convention(c) (MTAudioProcessingTap, CMItemCount, MTAudioProcessingTapFlags, UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>, UnsafeMutablePointer<CMItemCount>, UnsafeMutablePointer<MTAudioProcessingTapFlags>) -> Void = {
        (tap, numberFrames, flags, bufferListInOut, numberFramesOut, flagsOut) -> Void in

        // Audio coming out!
        let status = MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio(tap, numberFrames, bufferListInOut, flagsOut, nil, numberFramesOut)
        print("get audio: \(status)\n")
    }

    var callbacks = MTAudioProcessingTapCallbacks(
        version: kMTAudioProcessingTapCallbacksVersion_0,
        clientInfo: UnsafeMutablePointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque()),
        `init`: nil,
        finalize: nil,
        prepare: nil,
        unprepare: nil,
        process: tapProcess)

    var tap: Unmanaged<MTAudioProcessingTap>?
    let err = MTAudioProcessingTapCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &callbacks, kMTAudioProcessingTapCreationFlag_PostEffects, &tap)

    if err != noErr {
        // TODO: something
    }

    let audioTrack = playerItem.asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio).first!
    let inputParams = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: audioTrack)
    inputParams.audioTapProcessor = tap?.takeUnretainedValue()

    let audioMix = AVMutableAudioMix()
    audioMix.inputParameters = [inputParams]

    playerItem.audioMix = audioMix

    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    player?.play()
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out and report back